# Azure CDN access logs CORS information

Tags: azure, azure-cdn, azure-diagnostics

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/monitoring-and-access-log) describes different parameters of incoming requests but no information about Origin header.

Is there a way in Azure CDN to get information about requests CORS Origin headers?

Comment: Have you gone through this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-cors#azure-cdn-standard-profiles) which give you complete information about CORS and the headers

Comment: @saisakethguduru-mt, Thanks for the answer! Yes i know about CORS rules. But I don't need to filter incoming requests by Origin header or change response headers. I need to know the value of the Origin header of incoming requests if possible.